# Calculate values from counter metric in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have a counter metric in prometheus, how can I calculate last, avg, min, max values for my grafana like it is in zabbix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Prometheus [aggregation operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators), like:

```
avg(YOUR-METRIC[1h])
min(YOUR-METRIC[1d])
max(YOUR-METRIC[1w])
```

Or use the display options of the Stat panel in a Grafana dashboard:

[image]